# Call a parent:: function inside of call_user_func or call_user_func_array

Tags: php

Lets assume I have the following Class method:

```
public function handleException(fn, args) {
   try {
       call_user_func_array(fn, args);
   } catch (SomeException $e) {
       //handle
   }
}

function fn1(x, y) {
   return $this->handleException(parent::fn1, [x, y]);
}

function fn2(x, y) {
   return $this->handleException(parent::fn2, [x, y]);
}
```

This code does not work.
I was wondering what is the reason for that (Classes no being first Class citizens?)

Comment: See the examples in the [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotes

```
class A
{
    function f1($arg)
    {
        echo $arg;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    function test()
    {
        call_user_func_array('parent::f1', ['param1']);
    }
}


$b = new B();
$b->test();
```